# Cordova CLI - not updating config.xml

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have used the Cordova CLI 6.5.0 for the past 1-2 years, and it's acted normally.  We are upgrading our main app to `android@8.0.0`, which required a Cordova CLI upgrade.  In using Cordova CLI 9.0.0, I'm noticing that many things are no longer updating the config.xml file:

- platform adds - no longer see `<engine>` elements
- plugin adds - not adding `<plugin>` elements

I am making sure `--save` is used in the commands (which I gather is not even required anymore).  When I run a `cordova platform list` or `cordova plugin list` I see the expected platforms/plugins.  I also see that the package.json is used more heavily now.  However, the plugin/platform versions are not in the package.json so I can't imagine that's a complete replacement?

Lastly, some additional things I've tried:

- running `cordova platform android save`
- running `cordova clean` and `cordova prepare`
- adding and removing the platform (and ditching the related directories)
- Running an actual build (which works fine)

Is this "normal"?  Do these newer cordova versions not leverage the config.xml as regularly now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this was an expected change with Cordova 9.0.0.  I can see hints of the reason in the [Cordova 9.0 Lib release](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2019/03/18/cordova-lib-release-9.0.0.html).  Specifically [this change](https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/pull/750) that got pulled in.  There are also hints of the new package.json format [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/platform_plugin_versioning_ref/).

The config.xml file was extremely important to Cordova setup for years.  I would have expected this change to make a bigger splash in the way of documentation/announcements.  Maybe I'm just looking in the wrong places.

Comment: I still had to manually add at least one plugin back into `config.xml` manually to get it to work (as reported  [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/3199))

Answer (score 3):

Cordova 9.0.0

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
cordova plugin save
```

Comment: This was actually the solution for me, really simple.